# Share same environment on two machine

Tags: docker, operating-system, containers

Is there a way to have exactly the same environment on two different machines?

I would like to have a **full operative system with GUI** inside something like a Docker container that I can push in the cloud and then pull it from another machine.

Does anyone know how to do it or have any idea if this is even possibile? If it is not possible, why so?

Comment: Docker is not a vm, and it does not hold a full OS. It works on a 'shared kernel' model. If you want to run a UI then you'll either have to use windows rdp (if it's a windows UI) to access a UI running in a windows container, or run an xwindows server that you can mount from outside (if it's linux).

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to have a full operative system with GUI inside something like a Docker container

docker is not a virtual-machine and it is not intended for gui application. rather, docker should be used for lightweight applications\processes.

with that being said, you can still craft your host operating-system and the container to have a gui. for more information, see [jess docker images](https://github.com/jessfraz/dockerfiles/tree/master/firefox) and [this blog post](https://medium.com/better-programming/running-desktop-apps-in-docker-43a70a5265c4).

> Is there a way to have exactly the same environment on two different machines?

it is not clear from your question what do you mean by "same environment", but usually you can use [docker-compose file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/), and have all your configuration there. then you can share the compose file with others to pull\run\stop\etc the container.

Comment: Docker is not a virtual machine, and it is fine for UI applications.

Comment: Downvoting reduces my rating, so bad guess there @Mr. I downvoted because the answer is wrong. There's nothing wrong with running UI in docker -- I have lots of clients who do exactly that using rdp for windows.

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer: it is possible to run gui applications within a container, that is why i've included references to such cases. yet, it is not docker best practice, which is what i mentioned.

Comment: What makes you think it's not a best practice?